# Captcha Html Form

Tags: html, recaptcha

I followed Captcha's Tutorial and did this:
`Paste this snippet before the closing </head> tag on your HTML template:`
`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
Paste this snippet at the end of the <form> where you want the reCAPTCHA widget to appear:
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div>`
I want to know how I can make a form to use the captcha in. I just want a basic form that you have to solve a captcha before you can see some text. So you solve the captcha and press the button and it shows some text like `hidden message`. I can't find this anywhere. Help me! I prefer plain html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When your users submit the form where you integrated reCAPTCHA, you'll get as part of the payload a string with the name "g-recaptcha-response". In order to check whether Google has verified that user, send a POST request with these parameters

You need to send POST  to URL `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` with parameters what you see on your google reCAPTCHA account.

If you want BEFORE submitting form, add `data-callback` attribute to your `g-recaptcha-tag`. Inside that attribude set name of function that show hidden content only for successfully verifed users.

[For more info check reCAPTCHA documentation.](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param)

**Example**

In your javascript define function to show hidden content:

```
function alertSuccess() {
    $(".hidden.message").show();
    //alert("Success");
}
```

In reCAPTCHA

```
<div data-callback="alertSuccess" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="__YOUR_SECRET_KEY__"></div>
```